# What does "git push . HEAD:refs/for/foo" do?

Tags: git, gerrit

I was trying to push a new patch set to an existing change under review in Gerrit with:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/foo
```

but it failed with an error that the change was already closed. Then, I foolishly tried:

```
git push . HEAD:refs/for/foo
```

which seemed successful, but when I checked Gerrit, there was no new patch set. I think part of the reason was that my commit comment did not contain the Gerrit change ID that I wanted to push to. But what did the last command actually do? And how can I undo it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "`.`" argument means "push to this repository", and the refspec `HEAD:refs/for/foo` means "take the current commit that HEAD is pointing to, and make a new ref (similar to a branch, although those are usually stored as `refs/heads/something`) named `refs/for/foo` that points to the same commit".

Essentially, it's creating a new "branch" at the current commit, but since the desired name isn't in the normal branch name-space, we can't just use `git branch refs/for/foo`.

You should be able to undo it with `git push . :refs/for/foo` - naming an empty source to replace the ref with.

Answer (score 0):

`git push` accepts not only remote names but also addreses (see [Git URLs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#URLS) in the documentation).  In particular it accepts paths to local repositories, so `.` is just the current repository and you created a new ref in it.

You can delete it as usual with:

```
git push . :refs/for/foo
```